# Oreo - how to customize the foreground service status bar

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I start a foreground service that shows up in the status bar under android systems battery information.

Is there a way to customize the information (title, subtext, icon, ...) presented?

[image]

service code:  CODE EDITED

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CallbackTestWidgetService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10, notificationIntent, 0);

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context, "Test")
                    .setContentTitle("Test")
                    .setContentText("text")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.test)
                    .setTicker("test")
                    .build();

CharSequence name = "test";
            String description = "test";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("10", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription("test");
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            startForeground(10, notification);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default notification when no notification is posted by the app.

The reason why no notification is being posted (despite you calling `startForeground`) is that you are targeting API 26 or higher and not associating your notification with a [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). This causes your notification to be dropped entirely as per the note on that page:

> Caution: If you target Android 8.0 (API level 26) and post a notification without specifying a notification channel, the notification does not appear and the system logs an error.

You must create a notification channel, then include the id of the notification channel when building your notification.

Comment: I don't understand as the google doc (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) says 'A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the Ongoing heading.' and shows a standard example using a standard model: Notification notification =
          new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_DEFAULT_IMPORTANCE)

Comment: Yeah, that documentation is just out of date.

Comment: All of the [creating a notification page](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) is up to date. Just call `startForeground` with the notification you create.

Comment: Not very clear doc (it might be my english): so I still use the notification shown above, I add the channel and call startforeground. My app works perfectly but the app appears still in the android systems notification.

Comment: If you're still seeing the 'Test is using battery' notification, then there's still something you need to change. Edit your question with your updated code where you create your notification channel and use it when you construct your notification.

Comment: You've created a channel with the id `"10"`, but the channel id you set on your notification is `"Test"`. Strongly, strongly recommend using a `static final` variable for your channel id so you can keep track of them.

Comment: It works now (recommendation followed;)). Thanks! Pretty nice! It is showing a new notification on top of  the android systems notification. Is there a way to prevent my app/widget to appear in the 'app is using battery' notification or do we have to live with Android pointing a finger at us for using the foreground service. It's a pity especially as I paid particular attention at using systems broadcast receivers to consume the minimum resource.

Comment: If your NotificationChannel is of `IMPORTANCE_LOW` or higher, then you won't appear in the 'App is using battery' notification. (Note that you have to Clear Data / uninstall+reinstall your app to recreate the channel from scratch, which might be necessary if you had originally used `IMPORTANCE_MIN`).

Comment: I had LOW but I tried MIN, LOW, HIGH each time uninstalling the app. In fact it is as soon as I add my widget. Only the app is ok. Does the widgets have a different behavior?

Comment: I rewind on my stupid comment about the app Vs widget: the widget does the foreground startservice so it is normal that it happens only when I add the widget. Still changing the importance level doesn't make a difference I still appear in the App is using battery' notification.

Comment: I'm not sure why but the notification is gone now. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're building a Notification to pass to startForeground.  Use the createContentView function, just like you would for a normal notification you wanted to customize.

Note that this will only work on newer versions of Android, you probably want to use the NotiicationCompat class from the support library to support version specific api differences and test on a few different APIs of emulators.

Comment: This is helpful advice if they wanted to completely customize the notification, but that's not necessary just to change the icon, title, subtitle as requested - they just need to properly build a notification in the first place.

Comment: What is the difference with what I have done? The createContentView is not a notification builder?